# how to detect udp port scan in suricata?

Tags: ids, scan

I'd like to detect udp port scan in Suricata.

I searched google, but I didn't manage to find Suricata rule for detecting UDP port scan attempts. 
I saw before a snort rule for this scan.

How can we detect this kind of scan in Suricata?

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty of examples of UDP scans within the [ET community signatures for Suricata](https://rules.emergingthreats.net/open/suricata/rules/emerging-scan.rules).

One thing you have to keep in mind is that the very nature of a UDP scan. Someone is trying elicit a response through a socket on those ports via UDP. You may also want to consider creating flow rules related to the UDP protocol for saying # of connections with a null (or suspected common scanner payload) is seen sourcing from an offending host to multiple hosts in something like $HOME_NET and the flows bit words might be included [from_client, stateless](http://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/flow-keywords.html)